# How to make a simple repeat command in Delphi 6

Tags: delphi

I have a question. I have to make for school a project in Delphi 6 and I am quite familiar with Delphi 6.
I have to make a simple timer from 60 seconds to 0 seconds which changes in a Edit.Text but it's also good if it's in an Label.Caption.
It have to go like this 60,59,58,57 (..etc) 3,2,1,0. And at the end it has to open a new form
I have a idea it goes like this:

```
enter code here begin Repeat A:60-1 Until A=0 Form2.Show; end; end.
```

I know it's very bad, could someone help me please?

Comment: Clearly you are not familiar with D6

Comment: You are way out of your depth. You need to start with the most basic tutorial. Delphi 6 comes with one. Its modern equivalent is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_IDE_for_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, use a timer, such as with the `TTimer` component, eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //...
    Label1: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    //...
  private
    Counter: Integer;
    //...
  end;
```

```
// when you are ready to start the timer...
Counter := 60;
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Counter);
Timer1.Enabled := True;
```

```
Procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  Dec(Counter);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Counter);
  If Counter = 0 then
  Begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    Form2.Show;
  end;
End;
```

Comment: Where to put the codes of ''Counter := 60;
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Counter);
Timer1.Enabled := True;'' in my project? And what means ''Private''? And do I have to put Counter: Integer; in my VAR?

Comment: @ÖmerBastos Please take the time to understand the general basics of programming before asking about it.

Comment: I got an error of ''Undelcraded identifieter: 'Timer 1'

Comment: Please Jerry I appreciate your answer much and I'm only 17 years old i have to know the simple things. Could you help me with the error?

Comment: @ÖmerBastos Sorry but Stack Overflow isn't here to give you tutorials to learn Delphi. It's here to assist you with solving specific issues.

Comment: Dear Jerry Dodge, the time stucks at '59' seconds, could you please help me?

Comment: You must have lied when you said "I am quite familiar with Delphi 6", otherwise you would know how to work with VCL components, especially native components that are built into the core VCL component set, like `TTimer`. There are tons of documentation and tutorials available for Delphi, this is not the place for asking such questions. People are expected to have a rudimentary understanding of the things they are asking about, like placing components and assigning event handlers.

Comment: @ÖmerBastos Don't ask for tutorial. Put some effort in?

Comment: Okay, I only have to know 1 thing ! Where do you have to put the code of //when you are ready to start the timer

Comment: YOU decide that, not us. Put it where YOU need it.

Comment: Can you give me an exampel?

Comment: Like in your form's `OnCreate` event

Comment: Thx, but it still stucks at the 59's second. What must I do?

Comment: @ÖmerBastos You must familiarize yourself with the core fundamentals of Delphi before asking questions here about how to do simple things. We cannot see your screen or read your mind, so we have no clue why it's not working for you.

Comment: It's great that you're trying to learn Delphi Omer, but StackOverflow is not your tutor.  Maybe try Delphi chat rooms or Delphi forums?